# Do the languages of 0-turn PDA's coincide with the regular languages?

Tags: regular-language, pushdown-automaton

A PDA ([Pushdown Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton)) is said to be k-turn if, for any string w in its language, turn the direction of its stack at most for k times.
Also it is well-known that the language L is linear iff accepted by a 1-turn PDA. Now, is it true that the regular languages are the languages which are accepted by a 0-turn PDA?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**,
You can think a finite automata as a kind of  `0-turn PDA` in which a stack is never used.

A PDA is said to perform a turn if the stack goes up and down respectively in two consecutive descriptions of the automata. And for every Regular language a `PDA` can be constructed in which we empties `PDS` at the end of string acceptance.

Also, Regular Language is subset of Linear Languages in [Chomsky classification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252454/in-context-of-chomskhy-classification-of-formal-languages) (either Right linear or Left linear).

Comment: its good, but what about the converse? I mean how u can show that a 0-turn language is regular? maybe in this way: for a given pda with states=Q and stack symbols=G, construct a dfa with states=Q\times G, then the dfa move from (p,X) to (q,Y) by reading symbol 'a', if the pda move from (p,aw,X) to (q,w,Y).

Comment: Yes you are correct..An Finite Automate with `N` states can be simulate as `PDA` of `2 states` and `N stack symbol`. The reverse is what you said.